# check if file exist in cPanel directory php

Tags: php

I got a problem with my code. It's returning false. I have searched and tried some similar questions here but none of them helped. anyway, im using cPanel here. and i'm sure that the file really exists and so with the folder names. Hope you can help me with this. thanks in advance.

```
<?php


$filename = 'event-01.jpg';

if ( file_exists( $_SERVER{'/home2/user/public_html'} . "/MyProject/events/event-01.jpg")) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}

?>
```

i have also tried

```
$filename = 'event-01';

if (!file_exists('http://mysite.com/MyProject/events/event-01.jpg')) {   

echo "The file $filename doesn't exist"; 
}
```

Comment: This: `$_SERVER{'/home2/user/public_html'}` makes no sense. What directory are you trying to specify here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

To put it bluntly; this...

```
file_exists( $_SERVER{'/home2/user/public_html'} . "/MyProject/events/event-01.jpg")
```

is not `php`.

### Solution

#### Check a file exists

Assuming that the file path is actually:

```
/home2/user/public_html/MyProject/events/event-01.jpg
```

Then you should just be using that in `file_exists`:

```
file_exists("/home2/user/public_html/MyProject/events/event-01.jpg")
```

#### Server root

I assume that what you *actually* meant to do was:

```
file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/MyProject/events/event-01.jpg")
```

You *might also* like to try to `var_dump($_SERVER)` to see all of the information that it stores.

### References

`file_exists`: http://php.net/file_exists
`$_SERVER`: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: This is the better answer!

Comment: Hi Steve! it worked for me! Thank you so much for your answer! the way you answer my question is just so great! Everything is clear and informative. THANKS AGAIN! :)

Comment: No problem, good to know that you found it useful and solved the problem!! and thanks @Pier first time I've seen someone leave a comment like that so, erm, +1 for good sportsmanship! :) (your answer is still correct after all)

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, $_SERVER is a superglobal containing various server related information and unrelated to what you're trying to achieve.

Simply try this instead:

```
if (file_exists("/home2/user/public_html/MyProject/events/event-01.jpg")) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
```